# Power BI / Power Query - M language - playing with data inside group table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Hello M language masters!

I have a question about working with grouped rows when the Power Query creates a table with data. But maybe it is better to start from the beginning.

**Important information!** I will be asking for example only about adding an index. I know that there are different possibilities to reach such a result. But for this question, I need an answer about the possibility to work on tables. I want to use this answer in different actions (e.g table sorting, adding columns in group table).

In my sample data source, I have a list of fake transactions. I want to add an index for each Salesman, to count operations for each of them.

**Sample Data**

[image: Sample Data]

So I just added this file as a data source in Power BI. In Power query, I have grouped rows according to name. This step created form me column contained a table for each Salesman, which stores all his or her operations.

**Grouping result**

[image]

And now, I want to add an index column in each table. I know, that this is possible by adding a new column to the main table, which will be store a new table with added index:

**Custom column function**

[image]

And in each table, I have Indexed. That is good. But I have an extra column now (one with the table without index, and one with a table with index).

**Result - a little bit messy**

[image]

So I want to ask if there is any possibility to add such an index directly to the table in column Operations, without creating the additional column. My approach seems to be a bit messy and I want to find something cleaner. Does anyone know a smart solution for that?

Thank you in advance.
Artur

Comment: Please refrain from adding sample data in images. Adding as text will help contributors.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you may do it inside Table.Group function:

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Salesman"}, {"Operations", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "i", 1, 1)})
```

P.S. To add existing index column to nested table use this code:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(PreviousStep,each [index],0,(a,b,c)=>Table.AddColumn(a,"index", each b),{"Operations"})
```

Comment: Thank you for you advise. Unfortunately, this is not something I wanted to achieve.

Right now I have a table, that contains a row with another table and index column. I wanted to add index column in table with operations.

I don,t know how to add picture right here, but result is something like this:
Columns headers: Salesman | Operations | index
Row: John | [Table] | 1

And the same situation for each table.

Comment: Answer extended.